# How to pass Jquery variable to php variable?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to extract time **"10:30"** from `stime` jquery string variable

And transfer value "10:30" in a PHP variable like this format **"10, 30"**

```
<script>

var stime = 'Sat Dec 17 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';

<?php    
  $s = "<script>document.write(stime);</script>";    
  $e = "<script>document.write(etime);</script>";    
  $stime = substr($s,15,6);
 //substr_replace(string,replacement,start,length) 
  $convert_stime = substr_replace($stime,", ",3,1);
?>    
</script>

/**
 Output Will Be
 --------------
 Time: 10:30
 Converted Time: 10, 30
***/
```

Is there a way to handle it? Help me, any suggestion appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: PHP is run on the server while JS is run on the client (after page is rendered from PHP). You need to "pass" the value from the client side to the server side, either by POST/GETing the value via a form, or using AJAX.

Comment: BTW: There's no need for this whatsoever, you can convert time and manipulate strings in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

JQuery is Javascript, working on the client side. PHP is server-side. You will need to do some type of post back to send that data to the server. PHP cannot be invoked when a page has already been rendered by the client.

Comment: Aala gal keeto o sohnya

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible From the code above. Try using ajax.

Javascript is client side.
PHP is server side.

You can pass php variables to JavaScript (as you have done above)
But reverse is not possible unless you use ajax or something like that

Comment: // i want "10:30" part from mysrting and convert its format into "10, 30"

var mystring = "Sat Dec 17 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";

Output will be
Time: 10:30
Changed Format: 10, 30

Answer (score 1):

Javascript (and thereby, jQuery) isn't executed until the client's browser encounters it when loading the page. PHP happens on the server side before any code reaches the client. The only way to pass a Javascript variable to PHP would be through a GET or POST request (this could be via AJAX, or a synchronous page load).

For example, you could pass JS variable values into a querystring to be stored in PHP's $_GET variable:

```
//Javascript loads the page with variable values in the querystring
var firstVar = 'first_value';
var secondVar = 'second_value';
location.href = 'index.php?firstvar='+firstVar+'&secondvar='+secondVar;

//at index.php?firstvar=first_value&secondvar=second_value, we parse items from the $_GET variable into discrete PHP variables
$firstVar = $_GET['firstvar'];
$secondVar = $_GET['secondvar'];
```

Comment: i need to do this without reloading page

Comment: In that case, you need to make an AJAX call in which you pass `stime` and `etime` to your PHP script to be processed and returned to the page in the responseText.

Comment: And, to be honest, the string conversion you're doing (if that really is the extent of what you plan to do with this data) can be handled in Javascript entirely.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are fundamentally confused about Javascript and PHP.

PHP is server side programing language. It's being interpreted and executed on server machine and output is delivered to user usually via HTTP.

Javascript is client side scripting language and is executed on user machine using browser as execution environment.

What you want to achieve, can be done by sending HTTPRequest from your client side code (javascript) to server via HTTP POST method (or GET - depends on the semantics), where you can parse it using PHP. You can study more on topics like AJAX, HTTP protocol, javascript and client-server architecture fundamentals. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'pass' jquery variables to php this way.JQuery won't run on your server but on the clients.In your code,`$s = "document.write(stime);"` that part in `` tag will be treated as string.

Alternative way to do what you want is do the all the formatting job in javascript or do it in PHP or you can also pass the time variable via ajax and format it in PHP then get it in ajax.

javascript:

```
var stime='Sat Dec 17 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
var etime=stime.substr(15,6);
var res=etime.replace(":",",");
```

ajax version(if you must use the two method together):
client side:

```
var stime='Sat Dec 17 2011 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)';
$.ajax({
 url:"/your_php_script",
 data:{"stime":stime},
 success:funciton(data){
  alert(data);
}
})
```

php side:

```
  $stime=$_GET['stime'];
  $stime = substr($s,15,6);
  $convert_stime = substr_replace($stime,", ",3,1);
  echo $convert_stime;
```